# Eclipse not showing package which is already there

Tags: eclipse

I got in the trouble i am making some packages in my application all fine now i want to make a folder inside the source is good but when i copy some images in that folder one of my package is not showing in the eclipse.
and my work flow is like this

```
src/package1
src/package2
src/package3 
src/package4
src/folder/someimages there
```

Now in eclipse package explorer, If i want to give the same package name it is showing Package **Already exist**  `But i am not able to see the package in eclipse ....` why its happening 
 What should i do ... any help will be appreciated

**UPDATE**
It was a mistake my package structure is like this...

```
src/package1 
src/package1/package2
src/package1/package3
src/package1/package4
```

....

Comment: just see in your workSpace. U can create folder inside your workspace too.

Comment: that is  not my problem lets suppose i want to make a new class in my package1 how i would make it and compile.

Comment: Try "Refresh" on the project. This will sync the Eclipse cache with what is actually on the file system (can get out of sync when you copy files with other tools).

Comment: I have reinstalled the eclipse now its working fine thanks for your concerns .... really Appreciated :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you can't see `src/package1` is probably package presentation setting is set to flat. It will only display the packages that with files.

To change presentation, left click the arrow icon on your project explorer, change **Package Presentation** into **Hierarchical**.

Answer (score 0):

I have Resolved this by the help of what @dinup Kandel said i just write a class in texteditor and pasted it inside my first **package**

And guess what the package was visible  to me and i can add the class from eclipse there Thanks for the suggestion.... Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

Let us say you want to create file1.java in package src/package1 but it is not showing in workspace.
So go to package `src/package1/package2` and create a new file with name file1.java but give the package name src.package1 inside this file.It will automatically create file1.java in `src/package1`  folder and this package will start be showing in workspace.
for more information you can refer to http://www.coderanch.com/t/633775/java/java/eclipse-package-exists