# Cannot find existing package

Tags: java, eclipse

Today I wanted to create a new subpackage (`de.company.unittest.sub`) in an existing package (`de.company.unittest`). I'm trying to achieve that via Eclipse's "New Java Package" dialog. I cannot create the package, since it says

> Package already exists with a different case.

So I was looking through my source code, but I didn't find any classes with that package name. No luck.

Next I did a case insensitive "Find in files" search on all .java files in the whole workspace. Still no luck.

What else could be the problem?

Comment: this link might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279112/eclipse-not-showing-package-which-is-already-there

Comment: @user1994: the solutions there did not resolve my case. But perhaps I should have added the answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packages in Java correspond to directories on hard disk. Open the parent package (`de.company.unittest`) in system explorer. Check if a folder with that name already exists.

If so, it is for some reason not part of the Eclipse workspace. Press <kbd>F5</kbd> in Eclipse to update the project explorer. You should then be able to see and find the sub-package as well.